Is it a good idea to use `DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>>`
I've went through all the answers for this question
download a file from Spring boot rest service, realizing that the differences are related to the return value. Basically, there are two type families.

Return type for Blocking Servlet

ResponseEntity<Resource>

ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>
ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>
ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>


Return type for Async Servlet(Servlet >= 3.0)


2.1)DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>
2.2)ResponseBodyEmitter or ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter>
2.3)SseEmitter or ResponseEntity<SseEmitter>
2.4)StreamingResponseBody or ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>

Someone mentions that, for downloading big files, it might go OOM if we use ByteArrayResource.
IIUC, either FileSystemResource or StreamingResponseBody is friendly with big files, with http chunked encoding under the hood.

FileSystemResource servlet container thread is blocked but can take advantage of Zero Copy. More efficient for memory.
StreamingResponseBody servlet container thread is released. More efficient for CPU.

If that's true, will it be the best choice to use DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>> instead, since it's more efficient for both memory and CPU?
P.S. Let's ignore CDN and some other tech like BitTorrent for downloading big files in real world, and focus on comparing among these 3 ways(FileSystemResource/StreamingResponseBody/DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>>).

When seeing this kind of questions, I always want to ask the following questions: (1) Big File, how big is it? 100MB? 1 GB? 4 GB? (2) Do you know that there is a connection in your environment, download 4 GB Files What impact does a GB file have on your network? Is the entire network download bandwidth allocated to this connection first until the download is completed? Or is the download bandwidth of this connection displayed? Download bandwidth will be limited ? (3) Is there only one Does the connection occasionally download Big File? Or does it download Big File on almost every connection?

(4) So is your current network bandwidth sufficient? (5) This type of question is like hearing about executing a long process on the Web. The batch operation time is the same. Because the batch operation time is too long, so we will ask whether the Session Timeout time can be lengthened, or the batch operation takes up too much memory, how to increase the memory of the Web program.

@life888888 The size for a "Big File", really depends on the heap size of server side. 1 MB file is not so big for 1GB heap, but it is for 10MB heap.
I agree with you that for performance tuning in real world, it's necessary to collect many "variables", like download habit or bandwidth you mentioned. But for this question, it's not about performance tuning.
My key point is, why does nobody mention DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>>

As others have mentioned in the comments it all depends on the file size. But there's not only a CPU/resource but also a connection timeout aspect.
What you are essentially doing is putting the connection on hold until the server has prepared the response.
Unless you have some hearbeat mechanism in action (which is not the default for HTTP/TCP), for any other party a connection on hold is indistinguishable from a server failure or connection drop. Indeed if your "blocking" is too long, intermediate gateways may assume the connection dead/timeout and drop it.
In my experience blocking the HTTP response is somewhat acceptable if you can guarantee a delay below 30 seconds. Above 30 seconds things become unreliable. That's not just annecdotal, but from experience I've made while writing this long-poll library.
